# Fit table into page margins and center the second heading

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R}  % Journal abbreviations 
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in}  %topmargin control

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{>{}l 
                *{2}S[table-format=-1.2(2)] 
                *{2}S[table-format=-5.0] } 
\toprule & {$\textbf{Resonance 1}$} &{$\textbf{Resonance 4}$} & {$\textbf{Resonance 1}$} &{$\textbf{Resonance 4}$}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
  {\textbf{Approach}} & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ &$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ \\
   \midrule
1   & -0.31(9)          & 1.99(60)      & 475       & 11681\\
2   & -0.30(16)         & 2.00(35)      & 1453      & 8946\\
3   &  0.94(19)         & 2.00(63)      & -8289     & 13691\\
4   & -0.93(24)         & 2.00(36)      & -14394    & 8102\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \caption[]{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution focuses more on how the information is organized in the table. If the author intends to show the values of `β` and `χ²` in cases of `Resonance 1` and `4` using four approaches, then the first table below seems appropriate. If, on the other hand, the author intends to show that two different cases of `Resonance` are being studied and lists the obtained parameters (`β` and `χ²`) using different approaches, then the second table seems appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}

\usepackage[tight-spacing=true]{siunitx} %<--- added
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X
                    S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                    S[table-format= 1.2(2)]
                    S[table-format=-5.0]
                    S[table-format= 5.0]} 
    \toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\beta}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    {\textbf{Approach}} & {\textbf{Resonance 1}} &{\textbf{Resonance 4}} & {\textbf{Resonance 1}} & {\textbf{Resonance 4}} \\
    \midrule
    1   & -0.31(9)          & 1.99(60)      & 475       & 11681\\
    2   & -0.30(16)         & 2.00(35)      & 1453      & 8946\\
    3   &  0.94(19)         & 2.00(63)      & -8289     & 13691\\
    4   & -0.93(24)         & 2.00(36)      & -14394    & 8102\\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Combine $\beta$ and $\chi^2$.}
\end{table}
%
\begin{table}[h]\centering
    \begin{tabular}{l
                    S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                    S[table-format=-5.0]
                    S[table-format= 1.2(2)]                 
                    S[table-format= 5.0]} 
    \toprule & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Resonance 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Resonance 4}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    {\textbf{Approach}} & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$} &{$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$} & {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$}& {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$} \\
    \midrule
    1   & -0.31(9)      & 475        & 1.99(60)     & 11681 \\
    2   & -0.30(16)     & 1453       & 2.00(35)     & 8946  \\
    3   &  0.94(19)     & -8289      & 2.00(63)     & 13691 \\
    4   & -0.93(24)     & -14394     & 2.00(36)     & 8102  \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Combining Resonance 1 and Resonance 4}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the main problem came from the default  table-number-alignment, which is `center-decimal-marker`. Setting it to `center` solves the problem. To exactly fit matrgins, the best is to use `tabularx`, and change the first column specifier to `X`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx,rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}%for table decimals number
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}


\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[textfont=normalfont]{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\newcommand\apj{1925ApJ....61...38R} % Journal abbreviations
\addtolength{\topmargin}{.25in} %topmargin control

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X
    S[table-format=-1.2(2)]S[table-format=1.2(2)]
    *{2}{S[table-format=-5.0]}}
    \toprule & {\textbf{Resonance 1}} & {\textbf{Resonance 4}} & {\textbf{Resonance 1}} & {\textbf{Resonance 4}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
    {\textbf{Approach}} & $\boldsymbol{β}$ & $\boldsymbol{β}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ \\
    \midrule
    1 & -3.31(09) & 1.99(60) & 475 & 11681 \\
    2 & -0.30(16) & 2.00(35) & 1453 & 8946 \\
    3 & 0.94(19) & 2.00(63) & -8289 & 13691 \\
    4 & -0.93(24) & 2.00(36) & -14394 & 8102 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption[]{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I only slightly change column definition and add curly braces to all column headers. MWE load only necessary packages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,
            top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}%for table decimals number
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         group-four-digits}%

\begin{tabular}{l
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                S[table-format= 1.2(2)]
                S[table-format=-5.0]
                S[table-format= 5.0] }
\toprule 
    &   {\textbf{Resonance 1}}
        &   {\textbf{Resonance 4}}
            &   {\textbf{Resonance 1}}
                &   {\textbf{Resonance 4}}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}
    \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
\textbf{Approach} 
    &   {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$} 
        &   {$\boldsymbol{\beta}$} 
            &   {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$} 
                &   {$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$}   \\
   \midrule
1   & -0.31(9)          & 1.99(60)      & 475       & 11681\\
2   & -0.30(16)         & 2.00(35)      & 1453      & 8946\\
3   &  0.94(19)         & 2.00(63)      & -8289     & 13691\\
4   & -0.93(24)         & 2.00(36)      & -14394    & 8102\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
  \caption[$\beta$ and $\chi^{2}$ parameters values measured in this work for $Mg^{+}$ 3s in the $hv$ range between 54.50 and 55.52 eV]{The $\beta$ and $\chi^{2}$ parameters values measured in this work for $Mg^{+}$ 3s.}\label{table:betaSCALEFACTOR}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be the following modifications.

- You can use the [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package to set the a `\textwidth` table. It also provides the `X` column type( fills rest of the table space).
- With the option `[tight-spacing = true]` you will get tighter spacing. See [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package doc­u­men­ta­tion *5.6 Printing numbers* p.28.

> **[tight-spacing = true]:** Under some circumstances is may be desirable to ‘squeeze’ the output
>   spacing. This is turned on using the tight-spacing switch, which
>   compresses spacing where possible.

- To reduce/increase the spaces between columns in a table set `\tabcolsep` to `0.4em`/`0.6em` with `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.6em}`. (Default value is printed with `\the\tabcolsep`)
- [`showframe`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/eso-pic/showframe.sty) package : `\usepackage{showframe}` makes page margins visible.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=4cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}

\usepackage{showframe} %<--- added
\usepackage[tight-spacing=true]{siunitx} %<--- added
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.6em} %<--- added
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{}X
                S[table-format=-1.2(2)]
                S[table-format= 1.2(2)]
                S[table-format=-5.0]
                S[table-format= 5.0]} 
\toprule & {$\textbf{Resonance 1}$} &{$\textbf{Resonance 4}$} & {$\textbf{Resonance 1}$} &{$\textbf{Resonance 4}$}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3}  \cmidrule(lr){4-4}  \cmidrule(lr){5-5}
  {\textbf{Approach}} & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ & $\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ &$\boldsymbol{\chi^{2}}$ \\
   \midrule
1   & -0.31(9)          & 1.99(60)      & 475       & 11681\\
2   & -0.30(16)         & 2.00(35)      & 1453      & 8946\\
3   &  0.94(19)         & 2.00(63)      & -8289     & 13691\\
4   & -0.93(24)         & 2.00(36)      & -14394    & 8102\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
  \caption[]{}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```